# Rolling sum over a partition in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Code:**

```
data['rolling_sum'] = data.groupby(['User_id'])['Amount'].rolling().sum()
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Please help in figuring out the mistake in the code. An alternative method would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with level=0 and `drop=True` for remove first level of `MultiIndex`, what is safer because aligned by original index values:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
         'Amount':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'User_id':list('aababb')
})
data['rolling_sum1'] = data.groupby(['User_id'])['Amount'].rolling(2).sum().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

If assign only numpy array is possible values are added incorrectly:

```
data['rolling_sum2'] = data.groupby(['User_id'])['Amount'].rolling(2).sum().values
print (data)
   Amount User_id  rolling_sum1  rolling_sum2
0       5       a           NaN           NaN
1       3       a           8.0           8.0
2       6       b           NaN          12.0
3       9       a          12.0           NaN
4       2       b           8.0           8.0
5       4       b           6.0           6.0
```

Comment: Can we do this instead `data.groupby(['User_id'])['Amount'].rolling().sum().values`? Is `reset_index` faster?

Comment: @Ch3steR - I think safer, because aligned by index.

Comment: Ahh yes, understood. Thank you +1

Comment: @Ch3steR - added sample for see difference, its happens if not sorted values in `User_id`

Comment: Thank you for adding an example it's much more clear. Thank you.